# Como validar si un elemento existe en un objeto sin que salga el error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy recuperando un JSON de datos que mientras todo va bien trae por poner un ejemplo algo así como esta data:

```
{"data":{"val-1":"value-1","val-2":"value-2"}}
```

pero cuando las cosas no van bien puede traer algo así:

```
{"data":{"error":"errorEnData","descripcion":"Error en traer los datos"}}
```

entonces mientras dinamicamente estoy esperando a data['val-1'], si llegara data['error'] entonces me sale el error en cuestión, me gustaría saber como validar cual trae sin que este error tenga que salirme.

Comment: Si detallas un poco mas sobre la librería o forma como estas realizando la petición te puedo ayudar un poco mas.

Comment: No uso ninguna librería, es de mi propia API, la llamada que hago es dinámica y constante, generalmente de 50 a 100 llamadas una por segundo, cuando la respuesta (que es dinámica) responde en cada llamada, puede ser tanto la respuesta de arriba como también puede ser la respuesta de abajo, la cuestión es validar cual llega sin que salga el error cuando valido si llega una pero llega la otra.

Comment: Y como consumes los datos de tu API?. Bueno en todo caso tu API debería devolver un status code 400 o 500 según sea el error

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de como estés haciendo la llamada a tu API. Si estas usando Fetch API al hacer la llamada a la API esta devuelve una promesa en la cual puedes validar si la petición fallo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de Fetch y un enlace a la documentación

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch#Comprobando_que_la_petici%C3%B3n_es_satisfactoria

```
fetch('flores.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    response.blob().then(function(miBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(miBlob);
      miImagen.src = objectURL;
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Respuesta de red OK.');
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se esta generando porque primero no validas que datos devuelve el API antes de procesarlos

Deberías tratar de hacer algo como esto

```
const hasData = (value) => value && value.data;
const hasError = (value) => hasData(value) && value.error;

const respuesta = obtenerRespuesta();

if (hasData(respuesta)) {
  if (!hasError(respuesta)) {
    procesarRespuestaOK(respuesta.data);
  } else {
    procesarRespuestaConError(respuesta.data);
  }
} else {
   doSomethingWithNoResponseData();
}
``

De esta forma validas si vienen los datos OK y lo procesas de manera que necesites, en caso contrario, manejas los distintos posibles errores.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es que cuando renderices lo de tu API hagas una condicional para verificar que no contenga la propiedad error

supongamos que tu respuesta se llamada result, entonces:

```js
const result = {"data":{"error":"errorEnData","descripcion":"Error en traer los datos"}}
if (result.data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
  // aquí puedes mandar un alert
  alert('Ups...')
} else {
  console.log(result.data)
}
```